# Blood vessels in Chinese

Tags: translation

What is "blood vessel" in chinese? I searched an online google translation from english to chinese and got this:

> 血管

Other dictionaries such as cambridge also suggested this, but I am not sure about this. My context is mainly for biology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked from `National Academy for Educational Research (Taiwan, ROC)` ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cq1PDxwrHQdeBm_xnUOwB1wouALNuFhB/view)).

*出處/領域*•••      中文   •••英文詞彙

> *藥學*       **血管** vascular

> *生命科學名詞* **血管**    blood vessel

> *畜牧學*      **血管**  blood vessel

> *動物學名詞*   **血管**   blood vessel

> *獸醫學*      **血管**  blood vessel

> *畜牧學*      **血管**  vessel

> *魚類*        **血管** vascular canals

only 血管， others unlikely

血脉 is for traditional Chinese medicine or for culture (血脈）

> 静脉 is vein

> 動脉 is artery

Comment: I assume the link here was the reference in the answer; I [edit]ed it into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

血管 is fine.

A alternate and vety uncommonly used version may be:

> 血脉

or the Traditional version:

> 血脈

[Source](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%A1%80%E8%84%89)

Comment: 血管 is medical. It may appear with 肌肉, 神经. 血脉 is more inclined to lineage.

Comment: 他的主动脉(血管)破裂了; 他的身体里流着古老的血脉.

Comment: For bio, it is 血管. In the context of traditional Chinese medicine(中医), 血脉 may also be also a term, they say 血脉滞涩, but here 血脉 is abstract, they do not mean the real pipeline in body.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lingq.com/en/learn-chinese-online/translate/zh/%E8%A1%80%E8%84%89/

血脉/脈 could have cultural aspects:

1. 2018 reference

八九六四屠城(历史上的今天 20180604第102期)
人 心里 自由 的 血脉 更是 代代相承

2. 大典 reference

大典：民主 下
感到 高山仰止 只有 帝王 血脉 的 联系 才能 如此